# How to get the KML from the external url with geoXML3?

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps, kml, geo

Is it possible somehow to get the KML from the source out of the same domain. I mean to avoid the "[Same origin policy for Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)" somehow? (caching on our server is not the case since the application is **intended** to work with external sources)

The code below is what we're trying to accomplish (it give the error in case of external kml source).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({afterParse: useTheData});
    myParser.parse('http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/geo/?g=94823070@N00&lang=en-us&format=kml');

    function useTheData(doc) {
        // out callback
    };
</script>
```

What is the reason to ask if there is that policy? Since [google.maps.KmlLayer](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#KMLLayers) make this kind of [job](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-georss.html). Don't know how or I miss something. Really need it with [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) and to understand what is under the curtain!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are accessing a publicly available KML you can simply load it as a standard google overlay

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

Otherwise if you really need to use geoxml you will need to proxy the kml file (use a server side script that will load the file for you).

Comment: Thanks Michal, I've implemented the proxy technique, that is local domain proxy serves the remote content via `file_get_contents($uri)`.